# Is there a way to make abstract clearer in visualStudioIntellisense

Tags: visual-studio, abstract-class, intellisense

In WPF i have a BasePresenter class
that is herited by all my Presenter class 99+

Inside i have methode like
`protected abstract void InitFilters()`;

Who must be defined in my Presenter class
So in my Presenter class when i define my

```
protected override void InitFilters()
```

It has 99+ reference on it. So it's kinda hard for new developper than join the project to see the method is called by PresenterBase ect...
Is there a way to make intellisens make abstract definition and call first in reference?
Or even better not show all overide in reference on the

`protected override void InitFilters()` line
and only show the 99+ ref on the
`protected abstract void InitFilters()` one?

Maybe with some Attribut or think like this? I didn't found anything on google about this

Comment: Hi Jebik, any update of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make intellisens make abstract definition and call
> first in reference? Or even better not show all overide in reference
> on the protected override void InitFilters() line and only show the
> 99+ ref on the protected abstract void InitFilters() one?

You didn't share screenshots of this question, but if I understand correctly, what you want to know is whether you can manage **Codelens** behavior:

[image]

If I understand correct, then **the answer of your question is NO.**

Here are everything of this feature:

[Options, Text Editor, F#, CodeLens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-fsharp-codelens?view=vs-2022)

[Find code changes and other history with CodeLens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2022)

So far, VS has not provided a complex management method for this feature.

If you need this feature, you can share your idea on this place:

[Request a feature of Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest)

---

By the way, if you don't want to see those override methods, you can collapse them:

[image]

Any way, no such specific configuration method of this feature now.

Comment: I use you answer to mark it as resolved even if my issue isn't resolved i read a lot of thing and you appear to be right their is no way to do what i want.

I just want to add that in your screen you can collapse 3 overide in on click because it's all in same file.
My override are in different file one for Each Presenter who ihnerit the base. So I have 99+ file in codelense